# Getting an APP_SECRET for a page, not an app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, app-secret

Right now I am doing an http post request to post from a coldfusion file straight to my Facebook page. Right now, it is fully functional with the normal ACCESS_TOKEN for the page. My problem is, that to extend the life of the ACCESS_TOKEN, I need an APP_SECRET, which I don't know how to get for a **page**. Any tips? I really hope it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Any tips?

Tip 1: There is no such thing as an app secret for a page.
Tip 2: App secrets are for apps.

What type of access token is "normal"?  How did you get it?

Read the "Page login" part of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for more information on how to correctly get a PAGE access token.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of haha. The access token I got was with "GET http://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts", and it returned the access token with the normal life-span for the page. It works perfectly, my only issue is I need to extend the life of the access_token. Is there another way?

Comment: Facebook is deprecating offline_access permissions as we know it.  There is a 60 day version allowed now. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/ for more information on how to get a 60 day version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to GET/POST/DELETE things via pages, you need a admin user's access token and the manage pages permissions, and then get an access token for each of the pages you want to 'manage' through the application, which it seems you must have previously done, to have access in the first place.

As far as I know, getting that page information again, would refresh a page access token, as long as your user access token was still up to date. I'd suggest re-using the code you have for the original call to get the page data/access tokens.